# How can I have .json url print out for username retrieval

Tags: python, json

I Can get the information after the "data" tag to print from the url but that doesn't always give me a username. In the end I'll need to separate out all pages that produce a 404 error from ones that produce data aside from the 404 error.

```
name = "a"
url = ('https://www.reddit.com/user/{}.json')
def getusername(user1):
    response = urlopen((url).format(name)).read().decode('utf-8')
    responseJson = json.loads(response)
    return responseJson.get("data")
    if getusername(name) is not None:
        print(url)
    elif getusername(name) is None:
        pass
```

This will run, but won't print any data for me, so it's working, but I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong. I also need to know if this approach will print every url when "name" is replaced with a list of possible combinations of characters to make a username instead of just the urls that don't produce a 404 error.

Comment: `if response.statuse_code==200` after this process your repsonse data else pass for that url

Comment: Thank you, I used the code somebody provided saying what you mentioned and it'll print the url but it prints the url as its defined so it doesnt include the url that was run. I can force it to but id imagine with a list it would print all possible urls. It also still returns data for 404 urls.

Answer (score 0):

urlopen(url).getCode() should return the HTTP status code, which in the case of a 404 would return 404. You can check that to determine if you want to automatically skip that user.

If it is a 404, you can return None, if it is not a 404, you can return data. Then the rest of the code should work accordingly.

Edit: Here is a solution written using python 3. You should be able to modify it to use python 2. I believe the only real changes is modifying the urllib package to urllib2. I don't think urllib2 has the request part.

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.error import HTTPError
import json

name = "abc"
url = ('https://www.reddit.com/user/{}.json')
def getusername(user1):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen((url).format(name)).read().decode('utf-8')
    responseJson = json.loads(response)
    return responseJson.get("data")

try:
    if getusername(name):
        print(url)
except HTTPError as e:
    print(e.code)
```

Comment: Still not letting me print the url but I think its passing the 404s I cant tell since nothing will print still.

Comment: I added a solution using python3. Check it and try to convert it to python2